# Mongo Relations - class_name when used in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, relationships

First off this is my first question so hopefully I will provide all the info necessary.

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.0 and MongoDB with the Mongoid gem.

I am creating a module to be use across various classes.  I have attempted the below but it doesn't seem to work and I can not find any information as to how to set this up correctly, using the relation in a module and assigning a class_name:

```
module Core
 module Versioning
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do

   # *allows for tracking of various versions related to a root*
   has_many :versions, class_name: self.class.name,  inverse_of: :origin
   belongs_to :origin, class_name: self.class.name, inverse_of: :versions

end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So a typical module using ActiveSupport::Concern would be

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :versions, class_name: self.class.name,  inverse_of: :origin
    belongs_to :origin, class_name: self.class.name, inverse_of: :versions
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

And you use it like this

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  include M
end
```

Then Class A would have the association with versions and origin.  Maybe you are including Core Module instead of Versioning?

Comment: THanks for the reply @dotcomXY! I have finally figured it out, it turns out it should be self.name (not self.class.name).